# Glue does not work from the Docker Container

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-glue, docker-container, amazon-aurora

I am trying to run a simple Glue Job that takes the content from AWS S3 and dumps it into AWS Aurora Postgresql. While the job runs fine from the AWS Console, it just refuses to work while trying to run it out of a Docker Container on an EC2 instance. I have unchecked the "Require SSL" option while creating the Glue Connection. Despite that it is looking for some SSL certificate. I have kept the Aurora instance publicly accessible. Does anyone know what the problem is? Has anyone faced a similar issue?

```
20/10/24 10:20:17 ERROR Driver: Connection error: 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Could not open SSL root certificate file .
    at org.postgresql.Driver$ConnectThread.getResult(Driver.java:401)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:259)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper$$anonfun$8.apply(JDBCUtils.scala:895)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper$$anonfun$8.apply(JDBCUtils.scala:891)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper$.com$amazonaws$services$glue$util$JDBCWrapper$$catchSSLException(JDBCUtils.scala:852)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper$.connectWithSSLAttempt(JDBCUtils.scala:847)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper$.connectionProperties(JDBCUtils.scala:890)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper.connectionProperties$lzycompute(JDBCUtils.scala:670)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper.connectionProperties(JDBCUtils.scala:670)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper.writeDF(JDBCUtils.scala:814)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.sinks.PostgresDataSink.writeDynamicFrame(PostgresDataSink.scala:40)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.DataSink.pyWriteDynamicFrame(DataSink.scala:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:  (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at org.postgresql.ssl.jdbc4.LibPQFactory.<init>(LibPQFactory.java:124)
    at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:42)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:359)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:148)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:194)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:450)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.access$100(Driver.java:60)
    at org.postgresql.Driver$ConnectThread.run(Driver.java:360)
    ... 1 more
20/10/24 10:20:20 INFO JDBCWrapper$: INFO: using ssl properties: Map(loginTimeout -> 10, sslmode -> require)
```

Comment: did you figured it out?